# How to remove new line character in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe

I am trying to remove new line character from a dataframe by column level but some of the columns it is not working. Can someone help me what is going wrong here?

Example:

Df:

```
   col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
1  my,name,is,shiv:
2
3  ""blr"",ind
```

Expected Result:

```
   col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
1  my,name,is,shiv:""blr"",ind
```

Code I am trying:

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/iMedical/code_11032020/latest_script/PCYC_VOC_Data_Load.csv', delimiter = ',')
col = list(df.columns)
print(col)
new_f = df[col].replace('\n',' ', regex=True)
new_f.to_csv("D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/iMedical/code_11032020/latest_script/PCYC/test.csv", sep =',', index=False)
```

Comment: The fact that you have row numbers 1, 2, and 3 seems to indicate that 'blr' is part of row 3, and not the value of one of the columns of row 1. can you write df.iloc[0] and see what it prints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `\r\n` and `\n` with `''` then the expected output will come.

```
new_f = df[col].replace('\r\n','', regex=True).replace('\n','', regex=True)
```